# Wordpress: accidentally set site URL and HOME

Tags: wordpress

So in Wordpress settings, I set those two fields to from http://myDomain.com to  http://myDomain.com/wp and the Wordpress dashboard went dead on me. The site also displays funny.

I tried the first method here http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL , setting it back to http://myDomain.com, but no use.

1) How do I get everything back to normal?

2) Can I place have the home page of my site accessible at http://myDomain.com/wp and nothing else changed?

Comment: Did you change the dashboard_widget_options / home_url in the database?

Comment: the changes were made in the wordpress admin, I went to the general settings and changed the two URLs lsited

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the cPanel, you can easily change this.

Do this:

1. Login to the cPanel.
2. Access PHPmyadmin.
3. Once you click phpMyAdmin, in the left column click on the database
   that is used
4. Now click `wp_options` table from left.
5. In that table, you need to change two values: `siteurl` and `home`. just click edit button and add enter your new WordPress blog’s URL, then click the “Go” button to save the changes.

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the Site URL directly through the database, on the [Changing The Site URL Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) under the heading "Changing the URL directly in the database" it gives you a pretty good rundown on how to do it, this is how i'd do it.

1. Login to your SQL managing tool (most likley PHPMyAdmin)
2. Select your database
3. Backup your database (just in case)
4. Select the wp_options table
5. Change values siteurl / home to your domain
6. Now check the dashboard_widget_options value and update your domain there too (it should be listed 3 times, its a serialized array so plug [the values in here](http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/index.php), change the domain then copy paste back out, this should make things easier)
7. Go into the wp-admin section, click permalinks (under settings) then "Update Permalinks"

Report back!

Hope this helps..